# emacs lisp (elisp): modifying indent-for-tab-command in actionscript-mode

Tags: elisp

I'm using actionscript-mode in emacs, found here http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ActionScriptMode. I would like to modify it. The problem is in the behavior of the TAB command. I'm concerned with the case that the cursor is on the first column of a line that contains code already. Most code-editing modes in emacs handle this case by (1) performing an indentation calculation and adjustment, and (2) advancing the cursor to the first non-whitespace character. For some reason, the actionscript-mode does (1) but not (2). How can I modify it? I know a little emacs-lisp but not enough to follow the code. I'm not going to post the entire actionscript-mode.el, but there may be a clue in this section:

```
(defun actionscript-indent-line ()
  "Indent current line of As3 code. Delete any trailing
whitespace. Keep point at same relative point in the line."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (end-of-line)
    (delete-horizontal-space))
  (let ((old-pos (point)))
    (back-to-indentation)
    (let ((delta (- old-pos (point)))
          (col (max 0 (as3-calculate-indentation))))
    (indent-line-to col)
    (forward-char delta))))
```

The comment here says "keep point at same relative point in the line." Maybe I can just turn off that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The command back-to-indentation puts the cursor at the beginning of the line. I need to modify a few things because I want to preserve the relative position in the case that the cursor is in the middle of the line, past the first non-whitespace character, but if the cursor is positioned before the first non-whitespace character then I want to run back-to-indentation.